# Selecting element with JS by data attribute which contains quotes inside it

Tags: javascript, html

Create an element with a data attr

`<div class="component" data-bind="component: { name: "recently-viewed"}">`

Now I want to select it using `JS`:

```
document.querySelector('div[data-bind*="component: { name: \"recently-viewed\""]')
```

How can I get this to return the element? I am unable to edit the markup.

Comment: You want this element to select in jS or CSS.?

Comment: I will update the question, JS. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: It doesn't fix it but you're also missing the closing `}`

Answer (score 1):

Switch your quotes:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div[data-bind*="component: { name: \'recently-viewed\'}"]'))
```

```html
<div class="component" data-bind="component: { name: 'recently-viewed'}">
```

```
document.querySelector('div[data-bind*="component: { name: \'recently-viewed\'"]')
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsf33td7/)

Comment: I would need to be able to edit the markup for this.

Comment: As it is, I believe it's invalid markup, I think you'll struggle

Comment: Ha ha ha classic comment @JamieHutber

Comment: Ye, these sneaky guys. They are using Knockout, so I imagine its something to do with that

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use the other mini quotes

```
document.querySelector(`div[data-bind*='component: { name: "recently-viewed"']`)
```